# SQL: Select average value of column for last hour and last day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below image. What I need is to get `average` value of `Volume` column, grouped by `User` **both for 1 hour and 24 hours ago**. How can I use `avg` with two different date range in **single query**?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
SELECT user, AVG(Volume)
FROM mytable
WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 hour'
AND   created <= NOW()
GROUP BY user
```

Few things to remember, you are executing the query on same server with same time zone. You need to group by the user to group all the values in volume column and then apply the aggregation function like `avg` to find average. Similarly if you need both together then you could do the following:

```
SELECT u1.user, u1.average, u2.average
FROM
    (SELECT user, AVG(Volume) as average
    FROM mytable
    WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 hour'
    AND   created <= NOW()
    GROUP BY user) AS u1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT user, AVG(Volume) as average
    FROM mytable
    WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 day'
    AND   created <= NOW()
    GROUP BY user) AS u2
ON u1.user = u2.user
```

Comment: Not only is this not the best approach, but it will filter out users who have no records in the past hour.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation.  Postgres offers very convenient syntax using the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT user,
       AVG(Volume) FILTER (WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 hour' AND created <= NOW()) as avg_1hour,
       AVG(Volume) FILTER (WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 day' AND created <= NOW()) as avg_1day
FROM mytable
WHERE created >= NOW() - interval '1 DAY' AND
      created <= NOW()
GROUP BY user;
```

This will filter out users who have had no activity in the past day.  If you want *all* users -- even those with no recent activity -- remove the `WHERE` clause.

The more traditional method uses `CASE`:

```
SELECT user,
       AVG(CASE WHEN created >= NOW() - interval '1 hour' AND created <= NOW() THEN Volume END) as avg_1hour,
       AVG(CASE WHEN created >= NOW() - interval '1 day' AND created <= NOW() THEN Volume END) as avg_1day
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User, AVG(Volume) , ( IIF(created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , 1 , 0) )IntervalType
WHERE created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
      AND created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY User, (IIF(created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```

Please Tell me about it's result :)

Comment: Thank you Ahmad. That results in a syntax error `near 1` at `INTERVAL 1 HOUR`. I'm using postgres.